# How can I disable multiple file selection in IOS?

Tags: ios, file-upload, webview

I'm facing a bug in IOS with WebView, where it can't read video files when the HTML allows an input with **multiple** to upload files.

I want to disable multiple selection even if the HTML has the "multiple" on it.

In Android, we can do this:

```
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

So basically, I need to delete this line, to now allow multiple selection. I'm looking for some similar solution in IOS.